# VS2010 compiling errors for libfreenect (OpenKinect library)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, compilation, kinect, lnk2019

I'm installing `libfreenect` (`OpenKinect`) to interface the `Kinect` with `Arduino` for a 
tangible media project on Windows 7.  I'm stuck at the compiling stage 
in VS2010 with 61 errors of this type.

```
Error   1       error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol 
__imp___glutInitWithExit referenced in function glutInit_ATEXIT_HACK    C: 
\Users\Laptop\Downloads\OpenKinect Drivers\OpenKinect- 
libfreenect-3b0f416\examples\glview.obj glview
```

Full list here: 
http://goo.gl/EOrQQ

Here is a snapshot of CMAKE settings: 
http://goo.gl/uapTS

I have seen posts with similar errors but haven't found a known 
resolution, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

in the general case unresolved external symbol means you have a definition for a symbol that there is no declaration for.  This is usually solved by adding the appropriate .lib or dll file to your linker imports.

Answer (score 0):

I know that the question was asked two years ago, but I struggled with the same problem, too and perhaps others will find it helpful:
As for the version 1.2.5.0 and higher of the "*libusb-win32*"-library the name of the include files changed, I made a copy of the "lusb0_usb.h" header file and named it "*usb.h*" and  copied it to the "*system32*" folder of Windows and the "*VC/include*" folder of Visual Studio. 
And also be careful that you supply the right path to the "*glut32.h*" (NOT "../include/GL") and copy the "*glut32.dll*" and the "*phtreadVC2.dll*" to the "*system32*" folder, too.
Here is my "cmake" configuration:

[image]

After I build the "*libfreenect.sln*" project, it worked quite well and I could run the examples.